# Improve Arduino WiFly latency using protol

Tags: webserver, wifi, network-protocols, arduino

I have an Arduino with a [WiFly shield](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9367), everything works perfectly!
The thing is, when I want to turn on an [LED](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode), I open in my
webbrowser:

> 192.168.1.120/ledon/

(I made a program which handles this URL).

But the thing is; when I make a request, I must wait 1-2 seconds before I can do another one.
So, it is very long, and if I want to control motors, it is just too long.

So, instead of using an HTTP request, I want to use something else which can be faster.
Something "super fast".
I just need to tell the Arduino:
 - go direction 1
 - go direction 2...
 - turn on LED
 - turn off LED
 - tell me the light level (which return a int)

So it is just about a small amount of data.

Can you show me a way? (Telnet, UDP, [OSC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Sound_Control)?)

Comment: What kind of programming language did you use for your /ledon/ program?

Comment: Has anyone gotten any suitable performance out of wifi on an Arduino? Using the 'official' Arduino wifi I can only get 1.3seconds per http request. As OP noted, way too slow to control motors.

Answer (score 0):

For your arduino, have a look at just using sockets or even encoding the data in the URL requested. 
You shouldnt get less than about 0.8 Seconds Lag maximum. 
How big is your program for handling the Url /ledon/ ? 
Using pure packets (usually TCP) from your computer to the arduino is faster sometimes.. 
But you may need to code a application to handle the packets on the pc. 
There is the option of Javascript to parse data back and forth e.g. reading the light level and such.

Comment: Can you open separate sockets to the Arduino with HTML? I agree though that simple TCP packets can transmit in about 6 milliseconds.